# Цифровые часы как сделать

Tags: javascript, html

не нашел примеров в интернете. Как сделать такие вот часы?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам нужен эффект перелистывания?

Comment: да, обычные цифровые я находил, в принципе и не сложно, а вот пролистывание я не нашел

Comment: Если вы эти часы не находили в интернете, то это значит одно из двух: либо таких часов ещё не придумали, либо вы плохо ищете. Я склоняюсь ко [второму](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=477)

Comment: получается, мне нужно будет каждую картинку изменять под свой стиль? там их 2 папки

Comment: по другому никак не сделать?

Comment: [Скачайте с моего Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vDqhgfp6CiY5ANhUM_ALRWdGE_RCtd-F) Я думаю, это то что вы ищите, я как-то закинул себе и подумал что понадобиться. Вот понадобилось. Там архив, разберетесь.